# How to make Joplin app in my Android phone read-only?

Tags: applications, linux, dropbox

I am using Joplin note taking app both in my Ubuntu 20.04 PC and Android phone running Android 10. I sync my notes from both devices into my Dropbox account such that the notes are same in both my PC and phone. I edit and add new notes from my PC only and use my phone to only read the notes. But sometimes by accident, I end up editing or outright deleting my notes from my phone.

So how can I set my Joplin app in Android phone to read-only mode to prevent any accidental deletion or update?

Comment: There are multiple apps in Play Store named "Joplin". Please edit your question and include a link to the app in Play Store you are talking about.

Comment: @Robert most likely [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cozic.joplin) but it is best if OP links it themselves.

Comment: If this is about [this Joplin app](https://joplinapp.org/), the app is [open-sourced](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin). Perhaps you (or anyone) can [make a feature request](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin/issues) if this feature hasn't been implemented.